# Delimited string to rows in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-manipulation

I am looking to see if I can solve this problem using Excel- if not, I can write a script that would help me do this instead but it would be a little more time consuming.

Here is my data set:

[image]

This is just a sample of my data. The column on the left is an identification ID and the column on the right are some properties tied to that ID.

I want to manipulate the data in such a way that for each unique element on the right column, I have one row and these rows would have the repeated identification numbers (from the left column). The way it would look is:

[image]

I know about the "Text to Columns" feature in Excel but what I am trying to do seems more like "Text to Rows".

Any input is appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

A bit of a manual process but you could do the following:

1. Use `Text to Columns` to separate the properties.
2. Copy the properties and use `Paste Special` and `Transpose` to flip the column data to rows.
3. Fill the identification ID down to have it align with the properties.

If I had to fix up the sheet once that would probably be how I would do it. If I had to do it multiple times I would write a VB script to automate the process. You can see my [answer](https://superuser.com/a/570181/138254) to this other [question](https://superuser.com/q/570136/138254) about transposing rows/columns for an example of a script to do this.

Comment: It does work. The only thing is that I have to manually add empty rows to fill in the transposed data. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would probably copy it to a new Workbook or new Worksheet having them open side-by-side to make the copy/paste easier.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing it in PHP. Was a breeze. Anyhow, learnt a couple more thing about Excel through this.